# To compare 2 dates in different format in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime

Comparing 2 dates in different  format .both are in strings.

```
String date = "2019-01-01";         
String date1 = "Mar 13 2019 11:33 AM";
```

But getting error as Exception in thread "main" `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 13 2019 11:33 AM"`

```
// code :       
Date date11=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(date);  
System.out.println(date11);  

Date date22=new SimpleDateFormat("mmm dd yyyy HH:MM ").parse(date1);  
System.out.println(date22);  

if(date22.compareTo(date11) > 0) {
    System.out.println("date 22 is greater tehan date 11 ");
}
```

**Expected:** Parse 2 string dates in same format and then compare.
**Actual:** Getting the below error while parsing date .

Error facing  :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 13 2019 11:33 AM"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
        at aaa.basic.main(basic.java:24)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: m is for minutes. M is for month. And SimpleDateFormat is obsolete. Stop using it. Use the classes from the java.time package.

Comment: You're missing the token in your format string for AM / PM

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

you also need to specify the locale

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Addressing the `ParseException` on the `.parse()` method.

Your code *should* give the following error:

> Tue Jan 01 00:01:00 CAT 2019
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 13 2019 11:33 AM"
>
> at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:15)

The following date format should work. For more examples, see [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-date).

```
MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa
```

(credit to @MarcStrobel [for locale catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)));

This may be helpful. [See for example](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/util/date/java_date_before.php).

Use the [`.before()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) or [`.after()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) methods.

Your working example will be similar to:

```
Date date11 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(date);  
Date date22 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa").parse(date1); 
if (date11.before(date22)) {
    System.out.println("date 11 is before date 22");
} else {
    System.out.println("date 11 is after date 22");
}
```

as noted by @DorianGray, the `.compareTo()` method should also work, *but I prefer to be more specific before/after*.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesn't help, because he has a `ParseException` in his code. The comparision with `compareTo` is fine.

Comment: @DorianGray updated